# How to sort a bar chart without changing the query?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, charts, mschart

I searched and tried a lot of different things, but I can't find a way to sort my column chart.
We want to have the largest quantity at the top instead of at the bottom.

I can't change the query, but I need to sort the chart.

[image]

I tried the following:

```
ColumnChartMachine.Series(0).Sort(PointSortOrder.Descending, "Y")
```

and

```
 ColumnChartMachine.DataManipulator.Sort(PointSortOrder.Descending, "Y", "SeriesMachines")
```

Where I changed the Y to different values, and Ascending / Descending, just to see if it would do something, but no luck.

Any idea?

Comment: You don't need to change the query, just order the results (which are in a `DataTable` or a `List<T>`).

Comment: This did the trick.  I could sort my bindingsource, and now its fixed.  Thanks!
I was too busy looking at all the chart attributes that I forgot about the logic for a second ;)

Comment: While @Reza's suggestion of course it a good one I'm pretty sure that your first try at sorting works just fine. And using the DataManipulator will offer rather porwerful options, so I think your claim that it 'does nothing' can't be quite right.. Note however that in a Bar chart x- and y-axes are switched! (You do not show a Column but a Bar chart!!) Also note that if your x-values are non-numeric you can't use them for anything inlcl. sorting..

Comment: `Sort` should be called after `DataBind`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can't change the query, but I need to sort the chart.

You don't need to change the query, you should be able to use either of the following options:

1. Sort data on the data source (no matter it's a `DataTable` or a `List<T>`, without changing your query, you can sort the result, on client).
2. Sort chart points after calling `DataBind`

**Example**

Assuming you have data in a `DataTable` or a `List<T>`, like this:

```
var table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(int));
table.Rows.Add("FIT programmatiestation", 1);
table.Rows.Add("Atlas 1N36", 1);
table.Rows.Add("anilox cleaner", 1);
table.Rows.Add("Nietjespistool", 1);
table.Rows.Add("MORLOCK", 2);
table.Rows.Add("MA 2200 4k!", 2);
table.Rows.Add("Catena klein 2E21", 2);
table.Rows.Add("Automatische kokerslitter 76 mm", 2);
table.Rows.Add("ROP", 2);
table.Rows.Add("RDC 1", 4);
myChart.Series[0].ChartType =
    System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Bar;
myChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 1;
```

Option 1 - Sort data source:

```
myChart.DataSource = new DataView(table, "", "Value ASC", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);
myChart.Series[0].XValueMember = "Name";
myChart.Series[0].YValueMembers = "Value";
myChart.DataBind();
```

Option 2 - Sort chart after calling `DataBind`:

```
myChart.DataSource = table;
myChart.Series[0].XValueMember = "Name";
myChart.Series[0].YValueMembers = "Value";
myChart.DataBind();
myChart.Series[0].Sort(
    System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.PointSortOrder.Ascending);
```

Both generate expected result:

[image]